# Каким наиболее удобным способом можно хранить данные обьектов на стороне клиента  ?

Tags: c#, unity3d, массивы, xml

У меня имеются данные такого вида:

22 ,name of ship, name
23, attack,  12
24, shield, 30
25, speed, 20
26, other data, null

Словарь здесь не подходит, т.к значения могут быть разных типов. (Если только не писать свой велосипед IDictonary) Все эти данные относятся к одному обьекту, к примеру object1. Обьектов может быть любое количество. Интересную реализацию видел в php в виде ассоциативных массивов с несколькими уровнями вложенности. Не знаю правильно ли это, но судить и спорить на счет этого не буду. 
Появилась идея записывать все данные этих обьектов в xml файл, а из него уже читать в движке. Но если я не ошибаюсь, чтение и запись в xml файл в unity недоступны. 
Посоветуйте как мне быть ? Может есть библиотека для работы с xml для unity ?

На счет xml не гуглил, потому что мегафон модем...

UPD:
Нашел ответы по xml на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286308/how-to-write-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp-in-unity) и на [unityforum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/85925-Saving-and-Loading-Data-XmlSerializer). Но, не совсем понял, что означают пометки: [XmlRoot], [XmlElement] - корневой элемент и атрибуты ?

Comment: Проще всего использовать [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a65txexh.aspx). Эта штука встроена в язык, так что вам не надо будет заморачиваться даже с файлами. По сути это та же XML-сериализация, только за вас чтение-запись делает фреймворк. В худшем случае вам придётся имплементировать кое-где интерфейс `IXmlSeralizable` (но это просто).

Comment: @VladD, а можно маленький пример худшего случая ? т.е достаточно написать враппер для тех же attack, shield, etc и сохранять в config файл различные данные >(obj1 {attack = 20, shield = 30},> obj2 {attack = 25, shield = 20})  для каждого из обьектов ? только еще вопрос, как их различать ? по сути мне только нужно один раз заполнить все это данными, а затем только читать.

Comment: Пример худшего случая — это когда автоматическая сериализация данных делает не то, что вам нужно. Например, у вас есть свойство `X`, которое вы хотите в некоторых случаях сериализировать, а в некоторых нет, в зависимости от других данных. Или вы хотите сериализовать приватное поле.

Для вашего случая скорее всего нужно что-то такое:

    [XmlSerializable]
    class Ship
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Attack { get; set; } // и другие данные
    }

и в `Settings` кладёте `Ship` или `List<Ship>`, если их несколько.